# Powerautomate get file extension

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to get file extensions from Onedrive but get an error

Here is what I have setup.

**Current Setup**

[image]

Error

[image]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

thank you

images attached showing setup and current error

Comment: Show us the trigger JSON, it's tell you it's null so we need to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the trigger action. However, in this instance you can easily retrieve it from the Get file metadata action instead.

Try this expression

```
last(split(outputs('Get_file_metadata')?['body/Name'], '.'))
```